# Ray of Frost versus Stone Blood - is it redundant?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells

Is Ray of Frost [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1167)] now redundant when Stone Blood [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13741)] is available?

So we have Ray of Frost hitting a single creature:

> At-Will               Arcane, Cold, Evocation, Implement
>       Standard Action             Ranged 10
>       Target: One creature
>       Attack: Intelligence vs. Fortitude
>       Hit: 1d6 + Intelligence modifier cold damage, and the target is slowed until the end 
>            of your next turn.
>           Level 21: 2d6 + Intelligence modifier cold damage.

versus Stone Blood hitting up to 27 creatures *(if they'd be nice enough to arrange themselves in 3 x 3 x 3 cube)*:

> At-Will                Arcane, Implement, Transmutation
>       Standard Action             Area burst 1 within 10 squares
>       Target: Each creature in the burst
>       Attack: Intelligence vs. Fortitude
>       Hit: 1d6 + Intelligence modifier damage, and the target is slowed until the end of 
>            your next turn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stone Blood hurts all creatures, including any allies in the burst. Ray of Frost does cold damage instead of untyped damage, which could be useful if you knew your enemy had vulnerability to cold.

Comment: Good point on the Stone Blood hitting all creatures !